# Failed to resolve include text for file:SQLServer.ttinclude

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I updated to the version 3.0.0.3.  Dragged the new ActiveRecord directory in VS08, and added the newer dll.

I'm not sure whats going on yet.  When I try to compile the project I get that error.

My SVN server just lost my old version, so I'll have to download the older Subsonic version and see if that fixes the problem.  I have no clue what I did wrong in the configuration as I updated to 3.0.0.3.

(still a new users so I couldn't post a photo, but here a link to the error)

[link text](http://bigredsplace.com/error/error.png)

Comment: After playing with this for some time, I may have fixed it.  Do UNC paths affect the way <#@ include ... #> work?  I didn't think this would be an issue, but after moving the project from a UNC path to a normal, it now appears to be working?!?!  can anyone shed some light on that?

Comment: I expect Visual Studio gets confused when trying to resolve the path of the include on a UNC path and your experience seems to confirm this. Did this used to work with 3.0.0.2

Comment: I confirmed its a UNC thing.  I don't know how I over looked this.  I'm still new to T4 so I'm not sure if there is a way to get around this when one file references another file and the project is located in a UNC path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to close this issue.  Please Not UNC paths don't play nice with subsonic.  If you can.  Work with your project outside of a UNC path or do some fun research and customize subsonic to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your UNC path to  trusted zone in Internet Options?

See: http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=62664